# How to add program icons to the desktop?

Tags: unity

For example, I'd like a Terminal icon on the desktop.

Comment: Go to following Link:-
http://askubuntu.com/questions/67925/how-to-create-a-desktop-shortcut-in-unity

Comment: I added my answer to make a starter on your desktop for installed applications (for 14.04) here: http://askubuntu.com/a/474804/72216

Answer (score 0):

Open the Dash Home, its the icon on the top of the side bar. Enter Terminal in the search box then just click and drag to the desktop. You can also click and drag it to the side bar as well.

Comment: That doesn't work (it was the first thing I tried).