# Windows-like UI shortcuts in Ubuntu - Is it possible?

Tags: shortcuts

I'm very new to Ubuntu and I need one guidance that will make my management much easier there - I have a directory situated up in a tree of about 15 directories. It's tiresome to navigate manually from the UI each time or even from the terminal with tab --- Both ways are long anyway from the vast amount of directories to go through...

Can I somehow create a shortcut-icon (not a symlink I guess) that I will put in my Desktop and when I click it I will come to that folder just like in Windows?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a desktop shortcut in Unity?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/67925/how-to-create-a-desktop-shortcut-in-unity)

Comment: The type of shortcut you want is indeed a "symlink" ( = symbolic link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu desktop 15.10 (don't know about earlier versions), just stand with your mouse on the directory, right click on it, and than choose "make link"; A link icon will be created in your folder. Paste that link in your Desktop and you're done! :)