# Use desktop icon for running application

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I have used the answers given here [How to create a desktop shortcut in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67925/how-to-create-a-desktop-shortcut-in-unity) to set a custom application shortcut for spacemacs. While the shortcut works for launching the application, on running, the Emacs icon pops up and is used for selecting the program etc. This is unlike ordinary applications such as Evince where the running icon and launch icon are the same.

[image: Example_image]

Is it possible to get the custom icon to behave in an identical manner as Evince and other ordinary program icons? I am using Ubuntu 15.10.

Contents of `spacemacs.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Spacemacs
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Edit text
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/xc++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascaltext/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
Exec=emacs %F
Icon=/home/varunubuntu/.emacs.d/core/banners/img/spacemacs.png
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;TextEditor;
StartupWMClass=Emacs
```

**EDIT**: For clarifying after a few comments: the ideal behaviour for me would be that the Emacs icon should not pop up and the Spacemacs icon (put in by hand) should behave identically as the Evince icon.

Comment: Please add the content of your `.desktop` file to your question.

Comment: My bad. I've put it up now.

Comment: Aha. I think it's the line `StartupWMClass=Emacs`. Remove it and try starting Spacemacs again. Maybe you need to log out and back in for the changes to take effect, but usually not. It should not run as Emacs in the launcher then any more, does it?

Comment: Yes, on removing that line, there is no active icon in the launcher. However, using `Alt-Tab` still shows the Emacs icon as earlier.

Comment: Can you please open the Spacemacs window, then run `xprop WM_CLASS` in a terminal and click the Spacemacs window and post the terminal output line?

Comment: The output is `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "emacs", "Emacs24"` with both `StartupWMClass=Emacs` and `StartupWMClass=emacs24` (as given in one of the answers below).

Comment: Then you must set the `StartupWMClass=` to one of those two values, probably `StartupWMClass=Emacs24` is the best way, as @JacobVlijm already wrote.

Comment: commenting at your latest edit: yep, that's what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `StartupWMClass=Emacs` is incorrect. It should be:

```
StartupWMClass=emacs24
```

or

```
StartupWMClass=Emacs24
```

You can find out by opening a terminal window, type

```
xprop WM_CLASS
```

then click on the window of your application

Comment: That doesn't fix the issue; the behaviour is identical to the earlier one. See the comments on the question. The output is `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "emacs", "Emacs24"`.

Comment: @varun That is quite impossible, did you edit the line?

Comment: When in doubt, log out and back in. Also, where is the desktop file located? `/usr/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/`? Is one in both locations maybe?

Comment: I have tried different variants of `emacs24`, `Emacs24` and `Emacs` and the output is the same. Am I correct in understanding that I only need to restart the application or do I need to logout and login again? The file is located in `/usr/share/applications`.

Comment: @varun It depends; where is the launcher located, and do you have a copy locally and did you lock Emacs to the launcher as well?

Comment: Yes, it is working now after logging out and logging in with `Emacs24`. Many thanks!

Comment: @varun always glad it works. Sometimes the Unity launcher can be a bit stubborn. A log out/in can be refreshing then :)

Answer (score 0):

A note for future googlers: To get this working in Gnome 3 I also had to delete the file `/usr/share/applications/Emacs24.desktop` which used the same `WM_CLASS`. If I didn't, the one in `/usr/share` seemed to take precedence over my new desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications/Spacemacs.desktop`.

Comment: You can suggest an edit to that post.