# How does gnome-shell / dash-to-dock choose an icon for running java application (Talend)

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, .desktop, ubuntu-dock

I have installed Talend Open Studio by simply unzipping the archive in my home folder.
The application is launched via a shell script.
Then I created a desktop file :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Talend Open Studio
Comment=ETL
Exec=/home/franck/devel/outils/TOS/TOS_DI-linux-gtk-x86.sh
Path=/home/franck/devel/outils/TOS/
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/franck/devel/outils/TOS/24_talend-icon.svg
Type=Application
Categories=Development;ETL
```

I put it in `~/.local/share/applications/tos.desktop`
Finally I added the launcher to my favorite apps, so it stays in my dash-to-dock bar (Ubuntu Dock).

Now when I click on the icon (second on screenshot), TOS launches, but another icon (fourth) pops up for the running application; instead of the custom icon I put in my `.desktop` file, I get another (pixelized) icon.

[image: second icon from .desktop, fourth from... I don't know]

So here are my questions:

1. how does gnome-shell affect an icon to a running application?
2. where does it find a suitable icon? (a poor one in my case)
3. how can I force it to take my `.desktop` icon?
4. ideally, it would not show two icons while running (the launcher and the running one). What mechanism is implied here?

Comment: is your OS 16.04?

Comment: No, it's 20.04 under a Gnome Xorg session, with Dash-to-dock plugin.

Comment: then unity-dash?? did you install unity??

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/591341/739431

Comment: This is not exactly my problem. When I search for Talend, only my custom launcher is shown. It's only when running that another icon appears...

Comment: 0h sorry then.. but did u install Unity??

Comment: No, it's gnome-shell

Comment: found the solution in this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/726351/use-desktop-icon-for-running-application (but still don't know how gnome found the old pixelised icon...)

Comment: is it a snap app.. how did u install it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106776/discussion-between-alci-and-pratap).

Comment: You need to add a proper `StartupWMClass` entry.