# Gnome-panel failed to acquire bus name (gnome-panel as a program for adding a shortcut to the desktop)?

Tags: gnome

I want to organize the desktop icons using gnome-panel, using https://losst.ru/dobavlenie-yarlyka-v-ubuntu (ru)

Installed gnome-panel

`$ sudo apt install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel`

Calling gnome-panel

`$ gnome-panel`

I get an error

**`Failed to acquire bus name!`**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove GNOME Shell from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to install other desktop environment from scratch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233025/how-to-remove-gnome-shell-from-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-install-other-desktop-environ) Your way seems to be MATE, GNOMEs Hell is degradant even with GNOME FlashBack session.

Answer (score 1):

`gnome-panel` does not work with Gnome Shell. It is a component of **Gnome Flashback**. You install it as a part of Gnome Flashback.

- *Install the Gnome Flashbacksession*: `sudo apt install gnome-session-flashback`. This will pull in the entire Gnome Flashback desktop, including `gnome-panel`.
- *Switch to that session from the login screen*: On the log in screen, select your name and before entering the password, select the cog wheel. Select "Gnome Flashback" on the menu. Entering your password will now bring you on the Gnome Flashback desktop.

*Note:* Do not confuse Gnome Flashback with Gnome Classic. **Gnome Classic** runs on Gnome Shell, and is configured by series of officially supported extensions. **Gnome Flashback** is a different desktop, derived from the old Gnome 2 desktop.